How can I automate adding classes to an ontology in TopBraid Composer?
I'm completely new to TopBraid Composer and I've been given an excel sheet with a lot of data to add as classes to TopBraid composer (can't go into too much detail but for each bit of data I have to make 3 related classes).
Is there any way to automatically add 3 classes at once? Maybe using SPARQL or JavaScript where I just change all the appropriate property data?
I've just been adding them manually so far, not really sure how to get started with SPAQL or JS since I'm new to them
